# PHP - Get div content in javascript generated html

Tags: javascript, php, html

First of all i'm not english, so sorry if this isn't easy to understand.

I need get the html content of a div in HTML. This question is very common, and I think that I know how do it, but I have a problem getting the html source.

The page looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<body class="foo">
    <div id="blah"></div>
    <div id="blah"></div>
    <div class="page">
        <table id="layout">
              <div class="I_Want_This"></div>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

The problem is: I'm pretty sure that the part that I want is generated with javascript, so when I try to get the div I can't find it (because not exists yet).

In short: I need to get the page HTML source after run any javascript code in the page. ¿Is this possible with PHP?

**Edit:** the page is [this](http://www.dinorpg.com/clan/4#members), I want to retrieve the /div class="members"/ content...

Comment: The code that will find w.e HTML should run at the bottom, after everything has loaded. Have you tried that?

Comment: can you show us the javascript part of your code?

Comment: @Avik updated with the link

Comment: @SardàBonaire You can use jquery ajax to get certain part of the page, in this case you can use something like: `$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html .members" );` now replace the `#result` with the div id where you want the content to show.

I don't get the PHP part though. Maybe if you make your question a bit more clear, it will be easier to understand.